# Переключение комментариев при наведении css

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Хочу сделать чтобы при наведении на блок с фото он осветлялся, а остальные соответственно затемнялись, и сохранял свое состояние + перемещался треугольник, заданный через .opinoin__text--triangle::after. Hover работает только когда курсор наведен на блок, а как сохранить это состояние, как это сделать на css?

```css
.opinion__box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #472424;
    margin-top: 70px;
    word-spacing: -.36em;
}

.opinion__box__wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 60px 0 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.human__box {
    width: 180px;
    height: 140px;
    display: inline-block;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
}

.portrait {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url(../img/snow.svg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.human__box > p {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.opinion__text {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-top: 50px;
    opacity: 0.2;
    word-spacing: normal;
    padding: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.opinion__text > p {
    color: #fff;
}

.opinoin__text--triangle {
    position: relative;
}

.opinoin__text--triangle::after {
    content: ''; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 48%; 
    bottom: -50px;
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #000;
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.left__human__box, .right__human__box {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.left__human__box:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.right__human__box:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    
}

.transition {
    transition: 1s;
}

.center__human__box {
    margin: 0 20px;
}

.right__human__box > p {
    color: #a39292;
}
```

```html
<div class="opinion__box">
        <div class="opinion__box__wrapper">
            <div class="human__box left__human__box transition">
                <div class="portrait"></div>
                <p>John Snow</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <div class="star"></div>
                    <div class="star"></div>
                    <div class="star"></div>
                    <div class="star"></div>
                    <div class="star--empty"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="human__box center__human__box transition">
                <div class="portrait"></div>
                <p>John Snow</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <div class="star"></div>
                    <div class="star"></div>
                    <div class="star"></div>
                    <div class="star"></div>
                    <div class="star"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="human__box right__human__box transition">
                <div class="portrait"></div>
                <p>John Snow</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <div class="star"></div>
                    <div class="star"></div>
                    <div class="star"></div>
                    <div class="star--empty"></div>
                    <div class="star--empty"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="opinoin__text--triangle"></div>
            <div class="opinion__text">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                     Consectetur adipisci voluptates dolore reiciendis pariatur culpa corporis saepe eligendi,
                      aspernatur in quasi sequi neque eaque minus porro eos laudantium blanditiis deleniti.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если принципиально на `css` без скриптов, то никак.

Разве что можно запоминать состояние по клику: вставить скрытые чекбоксы и элемент с чекнутым чекбоксом будет осветляться, ну или можно поколдовать с псевдоклассом `:focus`.

С помощью `JS` можно без проблем реализовать такой функционал: при событии `hover` добавлять класс к элементу и удалять этот класс со всех остальных элементов, при этом если убрать курсор класс никуда не денется, пока не наведете курсор на другой элемент.

Comment: Спасибо, про radio button думал до этого. Сделаю лучше на JS, раз нет другого нормального способа)